# How to project Lambert Conformal Conic to WGS84 in Python?

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, wgs84, pyproj, lambert-conformal-conic

I am using pyproj to re-project Canada's Census Tract boundary shapefiles that are currently in "PCS Lambert Conformal Conic" system. I want to convert them to latitude and longitude WGS84 values.

1. Is "***PCS*** Lambert Conformal Conic" the same as "Canada Lambert Conformal Conic" system (since I could not find a code for the former)?
2. If yes, the code I found for "***Canada*** Lambert Conformal Conic" is ESRI:102002 and for WGS84, it is EPSG:4326.

My coordinates in Lambert system are x1, y1 = (8411012.879999999, 1438599.017145). After reprojection using the above codes, I get (-24.41452149523307, 11.570599554812532) which is definitely not in Canada. I get the same results when I use these codes in pyproj as well as on this website: https://epsg.io/. Since the coordinates are from Halifax, I expected the reprojected coorindates to be something near 44.6488° N, 63.5752° W (Halifax).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: PCS (Projected Coordinate System) Lambert Conformal Conic is a generic term and from the sounds of it definitely isn't ESRI:102002, you should be able to project using a custom projected CRS. As the source CRS is defined you should only need supply the destination CRS to project but check the PRJ file associated with your SHP file in notepad (or other text editor) to obtain the parameters to define a custom reference system if you have any problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try 3347 as input projection.

https://epsg.io/3347

Comment: Or 3348. 3347 uses NAD83 while 3348 uses NAD83 (CSRS).

Comment: Both of these work for me. Thanks for sharing.